# How to get the lastest version of MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++23

I found [MSVC Compiler Support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/23) at cppreference and noticed that std::print is available in MSVC 19.37. However I have no idea how to get it.

I have already downloaded the lastest version of Visual Studio 2022 **Preview**, but ended with a version of 19.36. Because that running this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << _MSC_VER << endl;
}
```

It prints:

```
1936
```

That makes me confused. I checked my VS installer and found that "lastest version of MSVC v143 x86/x64 build tools" is installed. I expect that I would have MSVC of version 19.37.

Comment: VS2022 isn't in Preview anymore - why aren't you running [the published versions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)?

Comment: @Dai I VS2022 has two version: stable and preview. I'm running VS2022 17.5.5 and VS2022 Preview 17.6.0 Preview 6.0, these are lastest versions.
On stable version, I found MSVC 19.35, and on preview version, I found MSVC 19.36.

Comment: @Dai I used VS2022 Preview for a try to C++20 modules a few months ago. That's the only version available to use modules at that time.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I thought you meant you were using prerelease VS2022.

Comment: The same way you get GCC 14 or LLVM 17 -- download the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/) and build it, or wait for a public release.

Comment: @cpplearner That's its C++ standard library. The compiler itself is closed-source.

Comment: Seems you have just noticed the difference between "is available" and "will be available". The fact that work is being done on 19.37 is a strong indication that 19.36 will soon be released, and then you will get a new Preview version. The [Microsoft Build!](https://build.microsoft.com/en-US/home) event on May 23 is not a wild guess

Comment: According to https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog#expected-in-vs-2022-177-preview-1 you need 17.7 preview 1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But `std::print` is a library feature, anyway

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, I will wait patiently until 17.7 preview 1 released.

Comment: It's hard for a beginner to follow the lastest trend of C++ :P

Comment: If you mouse-hover over the version numbers in that table (as the asterisk footnote suggests) you get the VS release number.

Comment: If you desperately need that function, why not use [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library until compilers add the print function from the standard library?

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, I just tried that. My curiosity is satisfied.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat That seems a poor recommendation. LLVM has been lagging for a bit now, at least compared to MSVC and gcc. It's possible they support this particular feature; I haven't looked. But they've generally been a bit behind the other major players the last couple years.

Comment: @sweenish Whenever I miss something in MSVC which I expected to be there I compare it in CompilerExplorer with g++ and clang. In most cases, it works in g++ and clang but fails in MSVC. Hence, I might have been under a wrong impression. I must admit that I'm using VS with MSVC in daily business but I never expect (or rely on) newest features.

Answer (score 1):

Now, VS2022 19.7 Preview 1 is finally released, and `std::pring` is available now.

This code now works:

```cpp
#include <print>

int main() {
    std::print("{}", _MSC_VER);
}
```

And it prints: `1937`

Happy to see this :)

Comment: How can I install that Visual Studio version?

Comment: @Pablo Checkout the [official site](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) of VS Preview